# An unbiased estimator for the 2 parameters of the gamma distribution?

Tags: gamma-distribution, estimators, unbiased-estimator

Nor Maximum Likelihood Estimators (MLE) neither the Moments Matching Estimators (MME) for the two parameters $\alpha, \beta$ (shape and rate respectively) are **unbiased**.

Is there a closed formula to compute an unbiased estimator for both the shape and rate of the gamma distribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No closed form for an unbiased estimator is known. The most recent work on closed form bias correction (which still leaves some bias in small samples) seems to be [Louzada et al. (2019, *The American Statistician*)](https://doi.org/10.1080/00031305.2018.1513376).